# Use WPF application to run multiple various applications using MEF

Tags: c#, wpf, mef

I am trying to create a WPF application that will be a central point for other applications.  The main application should be able to dynamically load other applications depending on user needs.  After doing some research, MEF seems like it might be the solution to this problem.

I am very new to MEF so I wrote a test app and tried to get MEF to work.  The test app defines a very basic ITool interface.  I was able to import multiple classes from class libraries without difficulties, however I was unable to import another WPF application.  Is this possible with MEF?

My main WPF application creates an instance of ToolContainer which creates and composes the parts.

```
class ToolContainer
{
    [ImportMany(typeof(ITool))]
    IEnumerable<Lazy<ITool>> _tools;

    private CompositionContainer _container;

    public ToolContainer()
    {
        AggregateCatalog catalog = new AggregateCatalog();
        catalog.Catalogs.Add(new DirectoryCatalog(
            "C:\\Application Development\\Tool Center\\Tool Extensions"));

        _container = new CompositionContainer(catalog);

        try
        {
            _container.ComposeParts(this);
        }
        catch (CompositionException compositionException)
        {
            //TODO: show error dialog
        }
    }

}
```

Here is the interface

```
public interface ITool
{
    String ToolName { get; }
    void OpenTool();
}
```

I  have created multiple classes that inherit from ITool and exporting works just fine. One example is here.

```
[Export(typeof(ITool))]
public class Class1 : ITool
{
    public String ToolName
    {
        get { return "....."; }
    }

    public void OpenTool()
    {
        //open the tool
    }
}
```

Now I want to import an entire WPF application that inherits the ITool interface.  The idea here being that external users can create their own WPF applications which will be able to be run from the main WPF application.  In the future the ITool interface will be much more advanced, but I'm trying to get the basics done right now.  I created a new test WPF project and modified App.xaml.cs to be the following:

```
[Export(typeof(ITool))]
public partial class App : Application, ITool
{
    public String ToolName
    {
        get { return "Tool Sample"; }
    }

    public void OpenTool()
    {
       //open the tool
    }
}
```

When I do this _tools does not contain my new WPF app, but does contain Class1.  Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?  Is there a better approach?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default, [DirectoryCatalog's constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd833448.aspx) only searches for types within `*.dll` files within the directory.  You can make this "work" by adding a second catalog to find types within .NET executables like so:

```
AggregateCatalog catalog = new AggregateCatalog();
catalog.Catalogs.Add(new DirectoryCatalog(
        "C:\\Application Development\\Tool Center\\Tool Extensions"));
catalog.Catalogs.Add(new DirectoryCatalog(
        "C:\\Application Development\\Tool Center\\Tool Extensions", "*.exe"));
```

That being said, I'd recommend against this.  Instead of having your users export Applications, I would recommend having them export a `UserControl` that implements `ITool`.  This will behave in a much more expected manner, since an "Application" is really designed and expected to run as its own Process, not be composed within a single parent process.